# modifying query not working : no property found exception

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to modify the card entity with below mentioned code.

```
public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, Integer>{

    @Modifying
    @Query(name="update Card c set c.status=4 where c.id=?1")
    public void setCardStatus(int id);

}
```

Card Class is associated with status.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="card_no")
    private String cardNo;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="status_id",nullable=false,insertable=true,updatable=true)
    private Status status;

... getter setters...
}
```

Below mentioned is the exception generated.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property set found for type Card!
```

Changing method name to modify also does not work also.

any help is appreciated please...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the name `setCardStatus`! Change the name to something like `changeCardStatus`